# How to display a view on top of another view in same activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I am have an activity in android application . It displays a view (lets say **CurrentView**)with a button in the centre of the screen . I am setting the content of the activity using :
setContentView(R.layout.layout_xml_file);
The layout xml file defines the button.

My requirement is that , when user clicks on the button , i need to show another view (lets say **NewView**)containing a listView on Current View.
The **NewView** transition should happen like this :
It should start from bottom of the screen and should take some proportion of the screen , say 3/4 or 1/2 . I mean the view's height should be configurable .
This **NewView** should be in the same activity . I do not want to create another activity for displaying it.
I don't understand which android widget is should use for holding the **NewView**

Thanks. Your help is appreciated ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a Relative Layout align to bottom and set its height what you want and inside Relative Layout Take Listview after that setVisibility gone. And when click button in activity setVisibility Visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:divider="#000"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how do i add the Relative Layout to the currentView.

Answer (score 2):

1. use LinearLayout - layout_weight attribute in layout.xml
2. View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE or View.GONE)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use FrameLayout for both views parent layout. Initially the list should be inivisble and button visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking something like this library ->
https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel